# How ti fix error dim(X) must have a positive length R

Tags: r, apply

```
 > tmpselected = input$sel_gene_promoter
         
       
 > tmpmydata_genes = mydata_genes[,match(colnames(tmpgeneids),colnames(mydata_genes),nomatch=0)]
 
 > tmpind = unique(na.omit(c(apply(tmpmydata_genes,2,function(k) match(tmpselected,k)))))
 
Error in apply(tmpmydata_genes, 2, function(k) match(tmpselected, k)) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length

> tmpmydata_genes 
 [1] gene_id chr1.1083  gene_id g292.t1    gene_id g467.t1    gene_id g624.t1    gene_id chr1.2796 
 [6] gene_id chr1.2959  gene_id chr10.1395 gene_id g1586.t1   gene_id chr11.59   gene_id g1922.t1  
10 Levels: gene_id chr1.1083 gene_id chr1.2796 gene_id chr1.2959 gene_id chr10.1395 ... gene_id g624.t1

> tmpselected
[1] gene_id chr1.1083
10 Levels: gene_id chr1.1083 gene_id chr1.2796 gene_id chr1.2959 gene_id chr10.1395 ... gene_id g624.t1



> class(tmpmydata_genes)
    [1] "factor"
> class(tmpselected)
    [1] "factor"
> is.vector(tmpmydata_genes)
[1] FALSE
> 
> is.vector(tmpselected)
[1] FALSE
> dim(tmpmydata_genes)
NULL
> dim(tmpselected)
NULL
```

I am missing out the simple fix that is causing the error. could anyone hint to solve.

Comment: Include what you expect/want the answer to be - it's not clear to me what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess you just want `match(tmpselected, tmpmydata_genes)` and don't need to use apply as match is already vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you can use   `traceback()` to identify more closely what line of code or function call threw the error.

Two guesses based on what you posted.  First,
try checking `dim(tmpmydata_genes)`  and `dim(tmpselected)`  to see what is actually in your source objects.  I suspect you don't want them to be factors.

Perhaps, alternatively,   you didn't read the man page `?match` .  In particular,

> match(x, table, nomatch = NA_integer_, incomparables = NULL)
>
> **Arguments**
>
> **nomatch**    the value to be returned in the case when no match is found.
> Note that it is coerced to integer.

So you're getting an `NA` now and then which `sapply` doesn't want.  set `nomatch` to some other value.

Comment: OP updated. However, the solution by pseudospin worked.